# How to read a list from a YAMLConfigutation

Tags: java, yaml, java-11, apache-commons-config

I have a YAML file that looks like this:

```
foo:
  bar:
    - entry1: 1
      entry2: a
    - entry1: 2
      entry2: b
```

(Where the actual list is much longer.) I'm reading this file using Apache Configuration2's `YAMLConfiguration`. I can see the data in the internal data structures used in Apache Configuration2, but I can't figure out how to get this list out. I actually have a class that matches the structure of the list elements, which is what I'd really like to read into:

```
class MyListEntry {
    public int entry1;
    public String entry2;
}
```

How can I get the data `YAMLConfiguration` into a `List<MyListEntry>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found (note this works for any `HierarchicalConfiguration`, not just `YAMLConfiguration`)

```java
// this will return a list of List<HierarchicalConfiguration<ImmutableNode>>, one entry for each element of the list
var subConfigList = hierarchicalConfig.configurationsAt("foo.bar");

List<MyListEntry> myListEntries = new ArrayList<>(subConfigList.size());
// iterate over the subconfigs and pull out the specific values of interest
for(var subConfig : subconfigs) {
    MyListEntry myListEntry = new MyListEntry();
    myListEntry.entry1 = subConfig.getInt("entry1");
    myListEntry.entry2 = subConfig.getString("entry2");
    myListEntries.add(myListEntry);    
}
```